# Reference a renamed variable with the same name in the source table

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to reference the new variable `DATE_YEAR` instead the original `DATE_YEAR` that I have in my Teradata database `TEST`. 
How can i get it?
I found nothing in Teradata documentation.

```
SELECT DATE_YEAR+1 AS DATE_YEAR, COUNT(1)
FROM TEST 
WHERE DATE_YEAR = 2016 GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: WHERE DATE_YEAR + 1 = 2016 GROUP BY 1;

Comment: In this case i can do this but i have other variables with more logic (`case when`, OLAP functions...) in which, for maintainability I want to use the new name.

Comment: then you have the answer from @jarlh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Standard SQL the columns in the SELECT-list are created *after* FROM/WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING/OLAP, but *before* ORDER BY, so you can use an alias only in ORDER BY.

Due to historical reasons Teradata allows reusage of an alias in any place, this is very convenient as you don't have to cut&paste or use nested SELECTs. But there are some scoping rules,  only when a column name is not found it's looked up in the alias-list. So the rough rule of thumb is: *Never assign an alias which matches an existing column name and then you can easily use it in any place:*

```
SELECT DATE_YEAR+1 AS DATE_YR, COUNT(1)
FROM TEST 
WHERE DATE_YR = 2016 GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up in a derived table:

```
select DATE_YEAR_ADJUSTED, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT DATE_YEAR+1 AS DATE_YEAR_ADJUSTED
    FROM TEST 
) as dt
WHERE DATE_YEAR_ADJUSTED = 2016
GROUP BY DATE_YEAR_ADJUSTED
```

That GROUP BY doesn't make much sense... Only one year anyway.

PS. I don't know Teradata, but I hope this works. ANSI SQL.

Comment: Yes, clause where haven't much sense, I put it to show how it shows 2017 while count shows the value for 2016 as example.

Comment: It's legacy code but I will try to go forward with your solution

Comment: When you rename it to `DATE_YEAR_ADJUSTED` (i.e. a non-existing column name) you can actually use it in WHERE (or any other place). See my answer. Of course this breaks all the rules, but it's really nice to have :)